# Float array data from a binary file using np.fromfile()

Tags: python, numpy, binary

Language: Python 3.6/
OS: Mac OS High Sierra/
Environment: Xcode

I have a binary file with different data types. I read it using the following command:

```
fn=open(filePathname,mode='rb')
```

I create a datatype as shown below:

```
dt=np.dtype([('a','uint'),('b','uint'),('c','uint'),('d','uint'),('e','uint'),('f','uint'),('g',float),('h',np.float32)])
```

I converted from binary using np.fromfile() as shown:

```
numpy_data = np.fromfile(fn, dtype = dt)
```

My expectation is I will have an array showing the 'actual' values in the array, but what I get is a bunch of bytes with appropriate types in numpy_data array.

Output

```
print(numpy_data['h'])
```

Result

```
[ 5.8315540e-39  6.0152250e-39  6.0582729e-39 ... -4.2051079e-07
```

8.4560821e+17  3.0060693e-10]

Problem - I know the numbers are not correct; I think it shows bytes data. If so, what is the right way to convert into their 'actual' value? I am using lumpy for speed and I don't prefer struct.unpack() method.

Comment: I've seen a lot of `bumpy` questions, but now it's a `lumpy` one?

Comment: Do you have documentation about how this binary file was created?  Your `dtype` loads, if I read it right, 6 bytes as `uint` (i.e. one byte per field), 8 bytes as the `float`, and 4 bytes as the `float32`.  Is that consistent with the creation documentation?

Comment: Oops `uint` is 8 bytes per unsigned integer, so that's 60 bytes per record.

Comment: Is the resulting size (`shape`) reaonable, what you'd expect?

Comment: lumpy is incorrect. numpy is what i typed but it auto corrected to lumpy!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using your dtype, with an in memory bytestring instead of a file:

```
In [279]: dt=np.dtype([('a','uint'),('b','uint'),('c','uint'),('d','uint'),('e','uint'),('f','
     ...: uint'),('g',float),('h',np.float32)])
In [280]: 
In [280]: x = np.ones((3,),dt)
In [281]: x
Out[281]: 
array([(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1., 1.), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1., 1.),
       (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1., 1.)],
      dtype=[('a', '<u8'), ('b', '<u8'), ('c', '<u8'), ('d', '<u8'), ('e', '<u8'), ('f', '<u8'), ('g', '<f8'), ('h', '<f4')])
In [282]: x.tostring()
Out[282]: b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?\x00\x00\x80?\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?\x00\x00\x80?\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?\x00\x00\x80?'
In [283]: np.frombuffer(x.tostring(), dtype=dt)
Out[283]: 
array([(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1., 1.), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1., 1.),
       (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1., 1.)],
      dtype=[('a', '<u8'), ('b', '<u8'), ('c', '<u8'), ('d', '<u8'), ('e', '<u8'), ('f', '<u8'), ('g', '<f8'), ('h', '<f4')])
```

---

What `uint` really should be `uint8` - 1 byte unsigned integer rather than the full 8 byte version?

```
In [300]: dt1=np.dtype([('a','uint8'),('b','uint8'),('c','uint8'),('d','uint8'),('e','uint8'),
     ...: ('f','uint8'),('g',float),('h',np.float32)])
In [301]: y = np.ones((10,),dt1)
```

`itemsize` for the 2 arrays is quite different:

```
In [302]: x.itemsize
Out[302]: 60
In [303]: y.itemsize
Out[303]: 18
```

But if the total size was right, either could be read with the other (10*18 == 3*60):

```
In [304]: np.frombuffer(y.tostring(), dtype=dt1)
Out[304]: 
array([(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1., 1.), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1., 1.),
       (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1., 1.), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1., 1.),
       (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1., 1.), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1., 1.),
       (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1., 1.), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1., 1.),
       (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1., 1.), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1., 1.)],
      dtype=[('a', 'u1'), ('b', 'u1'), ('c', 'u1'), ('d', 'u1'), ('e', 'u1'), ('f', 'u1'), ('g', '<f8'), ('h', '<f4')])
```

A mismatch is dtypes:

```
In [305]: np.frombuffer(y.tostring(), dtype=dt)
Out[305]: 
array([(      1103823438081,    70300024700928,   72340172838092672, 4607182418800017408, 72340173886586880,                 257, 7.8598509e-304, 2.3694278e-38),
       (4607182418800017408, 72340173886586880,                 257,   72408888003018736,          16843009, 4575657222481117184, 5.4536124e-312, 0.0000000e+00),
       (  72408888003018736,          16843009, 4575657222481117184,       1103823438081,    70300024700928,   72340172838092672, 1.0000000e+000, 1.0000000e+00)],
      dtype=[('a', '<u8'), ('b', '<u8'), ('c', '<u8'), ('d', '<u8'), ('e', '<u8'), ('f', '<u8'), ('g', '<f8'), ('h', '<f4')])
```

With a mismatch in dtypes we are likely to hit an error:

```
ValueError: buffer size must be a multiple of element size
```

Still a fortuitous mismatch in dtypes could explain a `fromfile` read that runs but produces wrong values, especially ones that look way off.

---

Based on your comment I wrote:

```
In [347]: dt1=np.dtype([('a','u4'),('b','u4'),('c','u4'),('d','u4'),('e','u4'),('f','u4'),('g','f4')])
```

I'm skipping `h` for the moment.

Now make an array with several records:

```
In [351]: x=np.ones((3,),dt1); x['g'][0]=10
In [352]: x
Out[352]: 
array([(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10.), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  1.),
       (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  1.)],
      dtype=[('a', '<u4'), ('b', '<u4'), ('c', '<u4'), ('d', '<u4'), ('e', '<u4'), ('f', '<u4'), ('g', '<f4')])
```

Write it, and then load just one count:

```
In [353]: np.frombuffer(x.tostring(), count=1,dtype=dt1)
Out[353]: 
array([(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10.)],
      dtype=[('a', '<u4'), ('b', '<u4'), ('c', '<u4'), ('d', '<u4'), ('e', '<u4'), ('f', '<u4'), ('g', '<f4')])
```

I'd suggest using this `dt1`, and using it to load just one record.  See if the values look reasonable.

I skipped the `h` because you describe it as `'h' is a float array such that it is 4*g bytes long`.  If 'g' is float this length is poorly defined; it should be an int of some sort.

If you have left `fn` open at this point, then `np.fromfile(fn, '<f4', count=n)` might work to load that 'h' array.  I would start with a small `n` just to see if this is promising, and later try a larger value or the open ended `-1`.

In other words, you description sounds like the file contains a header of fixed size, and then a variable size block of floats.

Comment: Incorporated your suggestion of changing 'uint' to 'uint8' ; it is still not right.  I don't know how the binary file was created except they are in little-endian byte order and except the last two fields 'g' and 'h' everything else is unsigned integer with 4 bytes each. 'g' is float with 4 bytes and 'h' is a float array such that it is 4*g bytes long.

Comment: I've made a suggestion based on this latest description.

Comment: It didn't work either. However, writing np.ones and reading it worked. I queries the data type it returned me numpy.int32 from a to f and for 'g' it returned numpy.float32.   Yes, you are right, the first six seems to be header. Also, what is the logic behind writing 1s and reading it? The file 'fn' is already open and it contains all datatypes. so, I am not clear what is the point in writing 1s and reading it.

Comment: I'm just illustrating the dtype action.  I  can't test my suggestions on your file!